# private getter and public setter?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

I was out of curiosity wondering if there was any scenario in which a private getter and a public setter would be desired or make sense.

`public string Foo { private get; set; }`

Also if there is any such use case for a protected getter.

`public string Foo { protected get; set; }`

Anyone got any scenarios or use cases for this?

Comment: No. If it's writable, why not allow to read it?

Comment: It's rare, but there might be some situations; like setting a password.